# How to choose a suitable navigation package

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hello everybody,**
my project is an outdoor autonomous navigation mobile robot using ROS, the sensors used are Lidar, GPS, encoders and IMU

---

i prepared the drivers for the sensors and actuators and each part is worked well separately with ROS, but now i want to connect and gather all the project so i am trying to find a suitable ROS package (providing autonomous navigation & SLAM),

---

**what are the main differences between the existed packages and what is the preferred package for outdoor navigation , "Any help and ideas are welcomed "**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272166/how-to-choose-a-suitable-navigation-package/) by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
Specifically, what packages are you looking at? There are many packages in the ROS ecosystem.

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-10-03**:
jayess
as i mentioned above packages for autonomous navigation & SLAM

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
You've mentioned what you want them to do (SLAM, navigation, etc), but not exactly what packages (names, links) you're referring to. How can someone tell you the difference between things if you haven't said what those things are?

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-10-03**:
jayess
ok sorry
i am asking for any package in ROS could do these things
i know only hector slam and navigation stack
so i am asking about the rest of packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have not yet integrated your other modules and performed navigation, I would start with gmapping to create the maps and the default navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-10-20**:
OK i'm going to use it. thank you sir.